# Query country border polygon from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

Is it possible to download the polygons of countries from OpenStreetMap using Nominatim web API? If so, how should I query its points?

In the example responses from Nominatim on OpenStreetMap wiki there is a `polygonpoints` property (attribute) on `place` object (tag), but it's not always present in search results when querying for countries. Also, what happens when the country "consists" of more than one polygon - several islands, for instance, can I query all of them?

If it's impossible to do with Nominatim, is there any other freely available API with such functionality?

Comment: AS per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: I think Overpass API would be the better approach here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It think it is possible with Nominatim, take a look at the query parameters listed in the [documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Search): The interesting parameters for you are the ones starting with `polygon_`, depending on what format you desire you can add `polygon_geojson=1` or `polygon_kml=1` (or the other ones) to your query.

If a country consists of several islands/polygons they are included as well, take for example Spain. The resulting geometry is a `MultiPolygon` for GeoJSON, `MultiGeometry` for KML and so on:

[image]

The query URLs may look like this:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=Spain&polygon_geojson=1&format=json
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=Spain&polygon_kml=1&format=json
```

Using `country=` instead of using the general `q=` as the search parameter seemed to yield better results for your use case.